# Loop into a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php

I have this array in PHP:

```
array( 
    "name" => "Cherry", 
    "desc" => "I'm a cherry.",
    "keys" => array(
            "Africa",
            "India",
            "America"
    ),
    "pict" => "image1.png",
)
```

And I want to loop into this and between `keys` to display to countries/continents.

This is what I have already tried:

```
foreach($details as $detail) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: is the array you show in the first place the `$details` array? If so, please edit your post to specify. What's missing in your post is what you got and what you expected when you tried the code you've shown. In this case it's pretty simple to guess, but please do not omit these parts so that when you ask a more complicated question, it doesn't end up closed as "unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to get other values in array along with countries:

```
<?php

$details = array( 
    "name" => "Cherry", 
    "desc" => "I'm a cherry.",
    "keys" => array(
            "Africa",
            "India",
            "America"
    ),
    "pict" => "image1.png",
);


foreach( $details as $key => $detail ) {

    if( is_array( $detail ) && $key == 'keys' ) {

        foreach( $detail as $country ) {
            echo $country;
        }

    } else {

        echo $detail;
    }
}

?>
```